# Orientation changes to portrait after dismissing iOS 14 Google Cast Network Access Prompt

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Our app is a streaming app that allows users to stream on Google Cast devices.

For iOS14, Google Cast has new network access settings prompt.

**Issue**
When the device is in landscape and the user clicks the Google Cast button from the player screen, the network access settings prompt is displayed in landscape mode but after dismissing the prompt, the player screen UI orientation is set to portrait.

How do I keep the player screen in landscape mode even after dismissing the Google cast network access settings prompt?

[image]